# How to make sure my android app can be searched in android market for all machines?

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I have an android app in android market. in general, all machine can search my app in android market. however, i got an user feedback that his device (Telekom move)cannot search my app in android market. Do you know how can i make sure my app can be installed and searchable in android market for all machines?

Comment: Your app will have some requirements (such as a touch screen etc.) that are not available on this device.

Comment: It largely depends on what settings did you set in your publising profile for the app and the manifest file. At least provide your manifest xml file here.

Comment: Hi Tom Medley, so i should set   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" /> in order that the telekom move can search my app ?

Comment: The Telekom Move does have a Touchscreen. This cannot be the solution. What is your Target Framework? But since the move is 2.3 this is most def. not the Solution. As far as the specifications and the hardware is concerned the Move is a pretty average device. Do you have a chance to test is with another move besides the one the user has?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can set the support-screens in the manifest

```
    <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

And you can also set availability to all countries in the Developer Console. To find supported devices, click on the link just beneath the country list in the console.